# Excel VBA named range scope, and intersect function

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges

I have a sheet where user picks a value from a dropdown. Then I search for that value on a different sheet, and return the that cell's address. The address is fed to a function that looks through each named range and looks for an intersect. I have thrown in some "debug" info on the function just to see if it's firing, and it's not. I have 3 sheets that it could potentially look through, so i have to be careful to not throw a 1004 error looking for an intersect on different sheets. I'm at a loss here. I'm sure it's something dumb, but I can't find it. Any help is appreciated.

```
For i = 1 To EndWRow
    For j = 1 To EndWColumn
        If woodSearch = Worksheets("Woods").Cells(i, j).Value Then
            
            Worksheets("Woods").Activate
            
            x = ActiveSheet.Name
            y = Worksheets("Woods").Cells(i, j).Address
            Set wMatchCell = Worksheets("Woods").Cells(i, j)
            
            If IsNamedRange(wMatchCell, woodRangeName) Then
                MsgBox "Range Name:= " & woodRangeName.Name & Chr(10) & _
                    "Range RefersTo:= " & woodRangeName
                    
                woodRangeNameString = woodRangeName.Name
                'Worksheets("Woods").Range(woodRangeNameString).Copy
                'Worksheets("Bag 1").Range("B2:H23").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
                'Worksheets("Bag 1").Range("B2:H23").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                'Worksheets("Bag 1").Range("B2:H23").PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
                
            Else
                MsgBox "Invalid Selection. Sheet name is: " & x & " and selected address is: " & y
            End If
            
            Exit For
            
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

Find named range function:

```
Function IsNamedRange(ByVal Target As Range, ByRef NamedRange As Name) As Boolean
Dim nm As Name
Dim i As Integer
i = 7

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Target.Parent.Name)
    For Each nm In .Names
        Sheets("User Entry").Range("B" & i).Value = nm
        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range(nm)) Is Nothing Then
                IsNamedRange = True
                Set NamedRange = nm
                Exit Function
        End If
    i = i + 1
    Next nm
End With
End Function
```

At the very least, I feel like this function should at least print all of the named ranges on my sheet (not really desired but I threw it in for debug) and it doesn't do anything. Long and short is the "else" ends up executing...

Comment: Sure that scope (not the refersTo) of your names is on the sheet? If it is on Workbook, you need to loop over the names of the Workbook. Check using the name manager.

Comment: They are all workbook scoped. If I loop through the entire book then the Intersect throws a 1004 error. Put in a On Error GotTo Next? But where to place? When I check in Name Manager, the choice to change scope is grayed out

Comment: Easiest would be to redefine the names so that scope is worksheet based.

Comment: Tested by making a new named range with only sheet scope. Works. Looks like I will need to delete and recreate each named range. *Sigh*

Answer (score 1):

You can make some changes to make it more generic.  Also updated the method name and returned the name as the function's return value - I'm not sure the Boolean + ByRef is getting you anything more than just testing the return value?

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim nm As Name
    
    Set nm = GetMatchedRange(Selection)
    If Not nm Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print nm.Name, nm.RefersToRange.Address
    Else
        Debug.Print "no name"
    End If

End Sub

Function GetMatchedRange(ByVal Target As Range) As Name
    Dim nm As Name, i As Integer, rng As Range
    'always operate on the parent workbook of Target
    For Each nm In Target.Worksheet.Parent.Names
        'Sheets("User Entry").Range("B" & i).Value = nm
        Set rng = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rng = nm.RefersToRange 'not all names refer to ranges...
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            'does this name refer to a range on the same sheet as Target?
            If rng.Parent.Name = Target.Parent.Name Then
                If Not Application.Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
                    Set GetMatchedRange = nm
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next nm
End Function
```

Comment: Tested and this works too. Thanks for responding! I ended up just recreating the named ranges and the original works as intended now. Long story short, don't create named ranges in Mac version of Excel. I had to create the named ranges on my Windows work laptop to have scope control of them.